# Power Automate Desktop - Selector Builder: Select UI Element based on HTML property

Tags: html, jquery, power-automate

I want to select a UI element (HTML) element based on it's innerText property.
I read elsewhere that the Selector Builder uses jQuery, but I have no experience with jQuery.

I have a dropdown menu where I need to select the item based on the installation number (Inst.:).

[image]

When I add the UI element I get this code:

[image]

```
body[Class="minside"] > div[Class="page"] > header[Class="sidebar-navigation"] > div[Class="installation dropdown show"] > div[Class="dropdown-menu show"] > a[Class="dropdown-item"]:eq(9) > small
```

If I understand this correctly it now picks the item based on a index number.

If I inspect the the element I can see that the installation number is located in the property "InnerText"

[image]

So I tried to remove the index number and adding innerText contains

```
> body[Class="minside"] > div[Class="page"] > header[Class="sidebar-navigation"] > div[Class="installation dropdown show"] > div[Class="dropdown-menu show"] > a[Class="dropdown-item"] > small[innerText*="103205"]
```

But it isn't working and I'm kind of stuck.

Can anybody help?

Comment: You don't have to specific the class name of your UI element

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
html > body > div > header > div:eq(1) > div > a:eq(9) > small
```

- You don't have to specific the class name of the UI element
- The number you use to locate the element is not correct

I knew this because the last Power automated desktop (PAD) Updated from Microsoft make everything more difficult to Add UI Element via recording

I just found it simpler by using Old PAD version.